# When is state available in componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs

I've build a text input component that allows the user to input a number into a text box. The component calls it's `onChange` prop if the user enters a valid number, and also sets its state to the string they entered. This is so that if the user enters "-" or "." by itself, the component can keep "-" or "." in the text box while the user enters the rest of their number.

When they finally do enter a valid number, it is parsed and passed to the `onChange` prop. The parent then sets its own internal state, and passes the parsed number back in the `value` prop.

The parent may also send a new number in the `value` prop for reasons other than user input, so I need to implement `componentWillReceiveProps` to overwrite the state with the new value when it is received.

This leads to a new problem: When the user enters "0." into the input box, it successfully parses to the number 0, which is passed to the parent via `onChange` prop, then passed back to the child via `value` prop. The component then calls `toString()` on it, which results in the string "0", which overwrites the "0." and makes it impossible to enter numbers with a decimal.

To solve that problem, the component first checks if the value passed in the `value` prop is equal to the string in the state, after parsing it (basically, if the two values are equal after canonicalization) and if they are, it doesn't override the value in the state, so that the string displayed to the user will remain unchanged.

But, inside `componentWillReceiveProps`, the state is the same as the old version of the state, and doesn't reflect the new characters the user has typed. It seems that operations are happening in this order:

1. User types a character.
2. Callback for character is called. Input is a valid number.
3. Component calls setState to update internal state representing input string.
4. Component calls `onChange` prop to pass new number up to parent.
5. Parent sets its own state.
6. Parent passes its own state back down to component in `value` prop (as a number).
7. `componentWillReceiveProps` is called
8. Pending state changes from component are applied.

The problem is caused by #7 happening before #8 (presumably, I haven't dug into React source to verify this). I've solved this problem by modifying `this.state` directly in the callback when the user types a character, as well as using `setState` with the same value, but I know that modifying `this.state` directly should be avoided if possible.

So my question is: can I solve this problem without modifying `this.state` directly? If so, how?

Comment: I'm don't see why your input needs to call `toString`. Why doesn't your parent send the value the input is expecting? It seems to me that your input component is trying to be too smart, and should just let the parent handle any logic about how to deal with the string value.

Comment: The parent doesn't store the string, it stores the number.

Comment: But it can, of course.. that seems like it would solve this problem.

Comment: At some point, that string needs to become a number. Also, this component is part of a larger component that allows the user to pick a color, and that component has the same issues of maintaining invalid states while the user is editing. I think applying that strategy in the general case would end up with a lot of duplicated validation logic that is at risk of getting out of sync.

Comment: I think you should post some code or make a fiddle out of this. Moving state and logic into parent containers to avoid this type of problem is a pretty typical React-way of handling things. If there's more going on that prevents this type of refactor then we'll need to know about it.

Comment: It's not why clear why any validation logic would be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just realized that I totally missed the point of your question. :|

You could do something like this:

```
const Form = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      number: {
        txt: null, // the text that displays in the input box
        val: null  // the actual number value
      }
    };
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    // assume that some `parseInput` function exists to get the number value
    let numberVal = parseInput(nextProps.number);
    if (numberVal !== this.state.number.val) {
      this.setState({
        number: {
          txt: numberVal,
          val: numberVal
        }
      });
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(newTxt) {
    // update number input
    let newNumberState = {
      txt: newTxt
    };
    // assume that some `parseInput` function exists to get the number value
    let newVal = parseInput(newTxt);
    if (newVal !== this.state.number.val) {
      newNumberState.val = newVal;
      tellSomeoneThatWeHaveANewNumber(newVal);
    }
    // update state (either txt or txt & val)
    this.setState({
      number: newNumberState
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <NumberInput
        onInputChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.number.txt}
      />
    );
  }
});

const NumberInput = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function(e) {
    // filter out unwanted characters
    const newValue = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
    // send new value to parent component
    this.props.onInputChange(newValue);
  },

  render: function() {
    let {value} = this.props;
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        type="text"
        value={value || ''}
      />
    );
  }
});
```